# Structuremap GetAllInstances returns too many copies

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap

Structuremap 2.6.4.1

In a test I have 3 instances as follows (AHandler, BHandler, CHandler)

```
public class AHandler : ICommandHandler<Event1> {... }
```

These are the only three implementations of `ICommandHandler<Event1>`.

For some reason this fails since it returns two of each instance!

```
Console.WriteLine(ObjectFactory.Container.WhatDoIHave());
ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<ICommandHandler<Event1>>().Count.ShouldEqual(3);
```

Here's the only mention of `Event1` in `WhatDoIHave`

```
 ICommandHandler\`1<Event1> (ICommandHandler\`1<Event1>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     Scoped as:  Transient

     27972b30-e8a9-46ce-9a8b-f6b2ae1f0907
     19e38715-a501-44d9-a003-4a5cec06034f
     7f4d0d0d-a20a-4347-86f3-104b0f586fca
     Ogre.Tests.Events.CommandHandlerOptions+AHandler, Ogre.Tests, Version=3.13.0.21139, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
     Ogre.Tests.Events.CommandHandlerOptions+BHandler, Ogre.Tests, Version=3.13.0.21139, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
     Ogre.Tests.Events.CommandHandlerOptions+CHandler, Ogre.Tests, Version=3.13.0.21139, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

So there ARE 6 instances in there but I have no idea what those GUID ones are or how I get just a single instance of everything.

I'm configuring structuremap as follows

```
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.Scan(s => {
            s.TheCallingAssembly();
            s.AssemblyContainingType<OgreEvents>();
            s.WithDefaultConventions();
            s.RegisterConcreteTypesAgainstTheFirstInterface();
            s.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
        }));
```

Upon investigation it seems like removing the `RegisterConcreteTypesAgainstTheFirstInterface` call fixes this so I'm guessing it conflicts with the following line. However both of these are conventions that I need (ie I have classes that implement multiple `ICommandHandler<>`s.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solved the issue

```
    ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.Scan(s => {
        s.TheCallingAssembly();
        s.AssemblyContainingType<OgreEvents>();
        s.WithDefaultConventions();
        s.Convemtnion<RegisterAllConcreteTypesAgainstAllInterfaces>();
    }));
```

Where

```
    public class RegisterAllConcreteTypesAgainstAllInterfaces : IRegistrationConvention
    {
        public void Process(Type type, Registry registry) {
            if (type.IsAbstract || type.IsInterface || type.IsOpenGeneric())
                return;
            foreach(var i in type.GetInterfaces();
                registry.For(i).Use(type);
        }
    }
```

Still not sure if that's the best way to do this...